# Making smaller models from pre-existing redundant models

Tags: deep-learning

Sorry for the vague title.

I will just start with an example. Say that I have a pre-existing model that can classify dogs, cats and humans. However, all I need is a model that can classify between dogs and cats (Humans are not needed). The pre-existing model is heavy and redundant, so I want to make a smaller, faster model that can just do the job needed.

What approaches exist?

I thought of utilizing knowledge distillation (using the previous model as a teacher and the new model as the student) and training a whole new model.

Answer (score 1):

First, prune the teacher model to have a smaller version to be used as a student in distillation. A simple regime such as magnitude-based pruning will suffice.

For distillation, as your output vectors will not match anymore (the student is 2 dimensional and teacher is 3 dimensional, you will have to take this into account and only calculate this distillation loss based on the overlapping dimensions. An alternative is layer-wise distillation in which the output vectors are irrelevant and the distillation loss is calculated based on the difference between intermediate layers of the teacher and student. In both cases, total loss may include a difference between student output and label, in addition to student output and teacher output.

It is possible for a simple task like this that just basic transfer learning would suffice after pruning - that is just to replace the 3d output vector with a 2d output vector and continue training.